# Hive Query Language Syntax Highlighting/Colouring

Tags: hiveql

I'm currently working with HiveQL and can't seem to find any tools for syntax highlighting. Does anyone know of any decent editors? Ideally I would like to find an add-on to Eclipse. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use Notepad++ . Once downloaded go to Settings -> Style Configurator -> Select SQL add user ext for your files (say hql). This will highlight syntax in Hive QL as most of the keywords are  same ion SQL and HQL.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can also add string a user-defined keyword as SQL doesnt not recognize it as a language keyword by default.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have also used below project to create a user defined language in notepad++ for hive.
https://github.com/lidermanrony/HiveNppUdl

Although i didnt like that the above project strayed from standard SQL formatting of notepadd++ so I edited hive.xml as below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just revisiting this, and to add to the list of possible IDEs, [Atom now has good support for HQL](https://atom.io/packages/language-hql).